# find serial com port

Tags: usb, serial-port

I'm using a `CH341-UART Converter` for sending some string data to USB port. How can I find the **COM** port number for connected device? For example in this program:

```
import serial      
ComPort = serial.Serial('COM24') # open COM24
ComPort.baudrate = 9600 
ComPort.bytesize = 8
```

`COM24` is my port. But how can I find the right com port number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under linux your devices have not meta-names like `com1` or so. Your usb-adapter is added to the `/dev`-directory with a driver specific name. The most usb-uart adapter use the name `/dev/ttyUSB*` where the `*` is a number beginning at 0. The best way to get this name is to view the changes of kernel messages via `dmesg` before and after plugin of the adapter. You should get something like that:

```
usb 4-2: ch341-uart converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

So you have to use '`/dev/ttyUSB0`' instead of `com24`.

But access to a device node is restricted to the root user. So you have to workaround this.

Comment: yes ... i find my device slug by `dmesg | grep tty` thank you

Answer (score 2):

Many Linux distros (typically Debian and derivatives) have a `/dev/serial/by-id` directory.  This shows the full "hardware" name of the serial USB device.  Watch this directory while plugging and unplugging to identify your device.

Create a symbolic link between that full name and some short convenient name in the user's home directory.  That full path (/home/me/myserial) is the "com port" to use in programs.  This is stable across plug/unplug/reboot because of the symlink.

Example:

```
my@host:~$ ls -lA /dev/serial/by-id
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Jun 11 07:21 usb-FTDI_FT232R_USB_UART_ANZ1SMDF-if00-port0 -> ../../ttyUSB2

my@host:~$ ln -s /dev/serial/by-id/usb-FTDI_FT232R_USB_UART_ANZ1SMDF-if00-port0 /home/me/myserial
```

This creates a symbolic link : `/home/me/myserial` that points to the USB/Serial converter whenever it is plugged into the host.

Comment: One other noteworthy thing: The user name should be in the dialout group to avoid having to be root to use the serial port.